# Return records with availability

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have a scenario where an `Item` is linked to a another `Entity` via a composite table. The `Entity` has a `Period` value of 1 = fullweek, 2 = midweek or 3 = weekend.

I want to return all `Item`s that are available, that is either has no link to an `Entity`, or has a link to a midweek or weekend but not both. The assumption is if an `Item` is linked to an `Entity` with a fullweek period it cannot be linked to another `Entity`, or if linked to a midweek can only be linked to a weekend and so forth.

I have got as far as left joining on `ItemEntity` to cater for outright availability but stumped on the other different cases.

```
 var query = (from it in context.Items
              join ie in context.ItemEntity on new { ItemID = it.ID }
                               equals new { ItemID = ie.ItemID } into itLeft
              from itJoin in itLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where itJoin == null
              select it);
```

The design should not be considered as an issue in this case.

Models:

```
Item
====
ItemID
ItemName

Entity
====
EntityID
Period

ItemEntity
==========
ItemEntity_ID
ItemID
EntityID
```

Comment: Post the code you have written so far.

Comment: M Bakardzhiev, edited

Comment: If you know how to write the SQL code you can try LinqPad to translate that to a Linq query

Comment: @JordyvanEijk LINQPad doesn't translate SQL to LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on `ItemEntity` and then count how many midweek/weekend `Entity`s are joined to that, and only keep the zero or 1 count `Item`s, excluding any `Item`s with fullweek `Entity`s.

```
var q = from it in Items
        join ie in ItemEntity on it.ItemID equals ie.ItemID into iej
        let ej = from ie in iej
                 join e in Entity on ie.EntityID equals e.EntityID
                 select e
        where ej.Count(e => e.Period == 2 || e.Period == 3) < 2 && !ej.Any(e => e.Period == 1)
        select it;
```

Comment: Thanks NetMage....does this cater for selecting Items where there is no entry in ItemEntity

Comment: Yes, hence ...`Count() < 2` - the count will be zero if `ej` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
 var query = (from it in context.Items
                     join ie in context.ItemEntity on new { ItemID = it.ID }
                                equals new { ItemID = ie.ItemID } into itLeft
                     from itJoin in itLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where itJoin != null && itJoin.ItemID == it.ItemID && ((itJoin.EntityID == 1 && (itJoin.EntityID != 2 || itJoin.EntityID != 3) || (itJoin.EntityID == 2 && itJoin.EntityID != 3) || (itJoin.EntityID == 3 && itJoin.EntityID != 2))
                     select it);
```